# Android emulator - не запускается эмулятор avd после переноса на внешний диск

Tags: android, android-studio, mac, эмулятор, sandbox

После переноса сдк на внешний диск не запускается эмулятор из консоли и из студии. Залипает после вывода и не падает с ошибками. Что делать, как запустить?

env

```
➜  Android env
ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/Volumes/Transcend/Android
ANDROID_AVD_HOME=/Volumes/Transcend/Android/avd
PWD=/Volumes/Transcend/Android
```

```
➜  Android emulator/emulator @Pixel_2_API_27 -verbose
emulator: Android emulator version 29.2.1.0 (build_id 5889189) (CL:N/A)
emulator: Found AVD name 'Pixel_2_API_27'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: 'emulator/emulator'; program directory: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator: emuDirName: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86/

emulator: Probing for /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file missing
emulator: try dir /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Setting QML to use software QtQuick2D: QMLSCENE_DEVICE=softwarecontext
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Running :/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "@Pixel_2_API_27"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386 @Pixel_2_API_27 -verbose
emulator: autoconfig: -skin pixel_2
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /Volumes/Transcend/Android/skins/
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//kernel-ranchu
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /Volumes/Transcend/Android/system-images/android-27/google_apis_playstore/x86//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /Volumes/Transcend/Android/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_27.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /Volumes/Transcend/Android/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_27.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /Volumes/Transcend/Android/.android/avd/Pixel_2_API_27.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 1536MB

emulator: VM heap size 256MB is below hardware specified minimum of 384MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 2 DNS servers: 192.168.0.2 192.168.0.20
```

systemlog

```
error   12:28:52.923547+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/emulator
default 12:29:13.099397+0300    emulator    FRONTLOGGING: version 1
default 12:29:13.099428+0300    emulator    Registering, pid=6140
default 12:29:13.100384+0300    emulator    CHECKIN: pid=6140
default 12:29:13.114453+0300    emulator    CHECKEDIN: pid=6140 asn=0x0-0xd00d0 foreground=1
default 12:29:13.158083+0300    kernel  Sandbox: 1 duplicate report for logd deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/emulator
error   12:29:13.158090+0300    kernel  Sandbox: WindowServer(226) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator
default 12:29:13.159785+0300    emulator    Registered, pid=6140 ASN=0x0,0xd00d0
default 12:29:13.160154+0300    emulator    Registered, pid=6140 cgConnectionID=7fd5f
default 12:29:13.163822+0300    emulator    BringForward: pid=6140 asn=0x0-0xd00d0 bringForward=0 foreground=1 uiElement=0 launchedByLS=0 modifiersCount=0 allDisabled=0
default 12:29:13.412610+0300    kernel  Sandbox: 3 duplicate reports for WindowServer deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator
error   12:29:13.412621+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-i386
error   12:29:13.413315+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.413446+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebChannelAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.413499+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5NetworkAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.413640+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QmlAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.413980+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebSocketsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.414393+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5CoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415419+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5GuiAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415627+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415683+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5SvgAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415729+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/libemugl_common.dylib
error   12:29:13.415776+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415819+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QuickAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415864+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5PrintSupportAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.415909+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QuickWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.664676+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/emulator64-crash-service
error   12:29:13.665242+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.665335+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebChannelAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.665405+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5NetworkAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.665712+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QmlAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.665770+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebSocketsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.665821+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5CoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666677+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5GuiAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666744+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666791+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5SvgAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666834+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5WebEngineCoreAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666872+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QuickAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666913+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5PrintSupportAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.666953+0300    kernel  Sandbox: logd(126) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/lib64/qt/lib/libQt5QuickWidgetsAndroidEmu.5.12.1.dylib
error   12:29:13.763523+0300    kernel  Sandbox: WindowServer(226) deny(1) file-read-data /Volumes/Transcend/Android/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64
```